# How to create random number for ID field In SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create random number for an ID field In SQL Server?

I want to create random number betwen 1000 to 9999.

How to create this structure?

Comment: Does it need to be a unique number, or do you just need a random number to appear?

Answer (score 2):

`RAND` is a built in function. It should meet your needs. This should give you the desired results: `select cast(rand() * 8999 + 1000 as int)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You've not mention whether you want random number generated as unique non-repetitive.

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;

---- This will create a random number between 1 and 999
SET @Lower = 1000 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 9999 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random;
```

[Source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/)

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
select number/power(10,len(number)-4) as number from
(
select top 10000 abs(checksum(newid())) as number 
from sysobjects s1 cross join sysobjects s2
) as T
```

Also refer this http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10810/generating-random-numbers-part-ii.aspx